# Magento2: How to create custom table in database?

Tags: magento2

I have created the basic model. But the custom table does not add in the database.

My Magento V2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your custom module add Setup/InstallSchema.php file

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $context->getVersion();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('tablename')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
                'identity' => true,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'primary' => true],
            'ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'firstname',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'FirstName'
        )->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Created date'
        )->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Updated date'
        )->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName('tablename', ['id']),
            ['id']
        )->setComment(
            'table related comments'
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Than enable module using

bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module  and

bin/magento setup:upgrade

> NOTE : if you have added the table creation script after the module is
>   already enabled than try removing the entry of the module from
>   setup_module table and than run bin/magento module:enable
>   Vendor_Module  and bin/magento setup:upgrade commands or try creating
>   table using UpgradeSchema script.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have followed the same step but table not created after ran upgrade command.

Comment: have you added the table creation script after the module is enabled ? Please check the entry inside setup_module table and delete the entry for your custom module and try executing the commands for module enable and setup:upgrade

Comment: Module already enabled.

Comment: module created successfuly  but table does not add in database.

Comment: please post your code .

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Codism_BasicCrud" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
        
    </module>
</config>

Comment: have you tried after  deleting the entry from the table "setup_module" and also removing the entry for your custom module from magento_root_directory/app/etc/config.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83565/discussion-between-rahul-makwana-and-masud-shaikh).

Comment: Your solution working well .